# What are the file places after you package a python program?

Tags: python, json, file, pyinstaller, software-packaging

I am wanting to package my program that uses over files to store user data locally, but I don't know what directory I should put in all the `json.load` and `json.dump`.  So right now, I have the directory equal to `json.dump(somelist,open('/home/username/filename','w'))` but when someone downloads it, the program won't work since it is a different directory. I am trying to PyInstaller but maybe PyInstaller will do it for me.  I was just wondering and I couldn't find anything on google but if there is something, please link it to me.  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to get the user's home directory:

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")
with open(os.path.join(home, 'file'), 'w') as sr:
    json.dump(somelist, sr)
```